# How does OS "protects" or "maintains boundaries" for different stacks of different threads within a process?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system

How does OS "protects" or "maintains boundaries" for different stacks of different threads within a process? I know that individual threads gets stack within process stack but what bothers me how OS  prevents other threads  from overriding it ?. Any pictorial representation would do a great favour.

Comment: In most OSes I'm familiar with, they don't. Separate threads within a single process are perfectly free to trash each others "private" structures.

Comment: but then  if two long threads (say 'A' and 'B')are running simultaneously and 'A' calls functions in order a1,a2,a3..and 'B' in order b1,b2,b3 ....then this information have to be saved i guess ?

Comment: Yes, they have *separate* stacks. That doesn't mean the OS does anything to *prevent* one thread from reading or writing the memory where the other thread's stack is located, thus corrupting it or causing it to e.g. return to a different location.

Answer (score 1):

if two long threads (say 'A' and 'B')are running simultaneously and 'A' calls functions in order a1,a2,a3..and 'B' in order b1,b2,b3 ....then this information have to be saved

The code, ie. binary instruction codes, for the functions 1,2,3 don't change, (unless the code is self-modifying - never do that). The A and B threads, running on different cores, can read the instructions concurrently without any problem and execute them independently.  It is far from uncommon for multiple threads to start at the same code address and so perform the same action on different data.

Processor registers are also OK - each core has a different set of registers in hardware & so they cannot 'overwrite' each other.  Note that this processor register set includes the stack pointer.

Stack data, eg. return adresses, local variables and parameter blocks, do not overwrite because each thread is allocated its own stack memory space. Threads A and B are running on different cores and so have their own stack pointer pointing at their own stack space.

Threads A and B can therfore call functions 1,2,3 independently and concurrently, running on different cores and, if the functions only use local vars and parameters, nothing extra needs to be saved or protected upon function calls and returns just because two, (or more), threads are running the functions.

Preemption only occurs when triggered by an 'interrupt' - either a system call from a running thread, or a hardware interrupt from a peripheral device that causes a driver to run, that the OS interprets, (using the interrupt parameters, scheduling algorithms and internal state data, in the manner of a state-machine), as a requirement to change the set of running threads.

Essentially, preemption requires the core register set, including the hardware stack-pointer, to be saved in a  Thread Control Block in the kernel, (allocated at the time of thread creation).  Another thread can be set running instead by restoring the register set from another TCB for another thread.  Essentially, the kernel swaps threads by swapping stack pointers - the thread stack data itself does not need to be saved - it just remains in memory until needed again when the preempted thread becomes running again.

This register-set-swapping is fairly easy, (!), on a single-core machine or if the OS decides that that the thread to be preempted is running on the same core that handled the interrupt.  If the thread to be preempted is running on another core, the kernel code has to issue a hardware-interrupt to the other core to force the running thread to run an inter-processor comms driver and so enter the kernel to get stopped - a whole new level of nastiness:)

Comment: "each thread is allocated its own stack memory space". Is the size of  that space same as allocated for a process (virtual memory)?

Answer (score 0):

different OS have different technique and mostly all move around Synchronization, different thread wait for different resources that's being in use by other thread , until that thread done with that no other thread can take it (matter of fact they lock it ).

its like u and your brother fighting for same cake and your mother told that you will get it after your brother, and gave fridge key to him, so until he's done with that he can keep the lock and ones he done he gave fridge lock to you.

u and u'r brother are different process fighting for resource(cake) in and u cant get lock until other is done.

Comment: preemption is something like your mother(thread) came in between when you and your brother fighting for cake interrupt you both, take lock of fridge, to take out some vegetables ,remember she cant go for cake, if she wan she too have to fight for it with you two, and if that happen then she may win coz of high priority(if you all waiting for same resource them scheduling comes in picture according to priority or what so ur algo is design to do) but if one having lock other have to wait.